# Creating a requirement.txt for a local working git repo without grepping the imports in .py codes

Tags: python, git, github, python-import, requirements.txt

I wanna create a requirements.txt for my git repo however how can I figure what are all the packages and their exact used version in all the codes in my repo without grepping all the imports? is there an automatic way to do this?

Here's all the grep result on imports in `*.py` files https://pastebin.com/raw/BuaqdL5H

Comment: You could install the program to a virtualenv and then do `pip freeze`

Comment: Ideally, you'd have created your `requirements.txt` _before_ now. Don't freeze your environment to a file; maintain your dependencies as you go and use them to _build_ your environment. By installing whatever you want into your global environment you've mixed up things you actually need for this project and things you don't.